# Dot product, ported from C to Swift

Tags: swift

This is how I posted a method from C to Swift. I tested it well, it seems to work. It's there a way to write this better, following good practices of Swift? The original is in C and the target must be in Swift.

Original C Code:

> ```
> inline float mac(const float *a, const float *b, unsigned int size)
> {
>     float sum = 0;
>     unsigned int i;
>
>     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
>         sum += (*a++) * (*b++);
>     return sum;
> }
> ```

and the translation to Swift:

```
func mac(a : [Float], b : [Float], size : Int) -> Float
{
    var sum : Float = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += (a[i]) * (b[i]);
    }
return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can remove the `size` parameter as arrays know their own size in Swift, and use the `zip`, `map` and `reduce` functions to perform the computation rather than the C-style `for` loop, which is now unavailable in the latest versions of Swift (as is `i++`):

```
func mac(a: [Float], b: [Float]) -> Float {
    return zip(a, b).map(*).reduce(0, +)
}
```

- The `zip` function takes two arrays and makes a single array of tuples, with each tuple containing the nth element from each array.
- The `map` function changes each element of the array with a user-supplied function. In this case, the multiplication operator is passed in, which multiplies each pair.
- The `reduce` function performs the task of summing each result (starting at 0).

Comment: But just for my knowledge, was my implementation correct from the functionality point of view?

Comment: Yes, it looked correct, but can be considered "old fashioned" for use in Swift.

Comment: Also, C-style for loops won't work in future versions of Swift.